# firewalld + squid : how-to setup a proxy

Tags: linux, networking, proxy, squid, firewalld

infra-server with IP x.x.x.x (with no internet connectivity) does the following request:

```
$ wget http://google.com
--2016-11-04 09:32:55--  http://google.com/
Resolving google.com (google.com)... 172.217.22.110, 2a00:1450:4001:81d::200e
Connecting to google.com (google.com)|172.217.22.110|:8888... failed: Connection timed out.
```

proxy-server (squid listening on 8888) has the following interfaces:
eth1: 1.1.1.1 where all incoming requests from infra-server are coming in
eth2: 2.2.2.2 which has internet connectivity with a default route (80,443) because its address is translated in the firewall (gateway)

By doing a tcpdump on proxy-server and eth1 (incoming interface) I see correctly the traffic arriving:

```
09:49:10.033951 IP  x.x.x.x.45977 > 1.1.1.1.8888: Flags [S], seq 258250387, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3204336400 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
09:49:11.034310 IP  x.x.x.x.45977 > 1.1.1.1.8888: Flags [S], seq 258250387, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3204337402 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
09:49:13.042720 IP  x.x.x.x.45977 > 1.1.1.1.8888: Flags [S], seq 258250387, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3204339408 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
09:49:17.047283 IP  x.x.x.x.45977 > 1.1.1.1.8888: Flags [S], seq 258250387, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3204343416 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
09:49:22.303238 IP  x.x.x.x.45977 > 1.1.1.1.8888: Flags [R], seq 258250387, win 1400, length 0
09:49:25.060419 IP  x.x.x.x.45977 > 1.1.1.1.8888: Flags [S], seq 258250387, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3204351424 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
09:49:30.321096 IP  x.x.x.x.45977 > 1.1.1.1.8888: Flags [R], seq 258250387, win 1400, length 0
```

By doing a tcpdump on the proxy-server and eth2 (outgoing interface) I do not see any outgoing http traffic

What I have changed in the configuration of squid is only the following:

```
acl infra-server src x.x.x.x/32
http_access allow infra-server
http_port 1.1.1.1:8888
```

System-wise, SElinux is set to permissive:

```
# getenforce
Permissive
```

and how firewalld is configured is:

```
# firewall-cmd --list-all --zone=internal
internal (active)
  interfaces: eth1
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client ipp-client mdns samba-client ssh
  ports: 8888/tcp
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 

# firewall-cmd --list-all --zone=external
external (active)
  interfaces: eth2
  sources: 
  services: http https ssh
  ports: 
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

I just need the rule to forward traffic from eth1 to eth2 (I think).